# Crystal Reports - How to suppress a page header on the first page of a group?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have a report where each group is about 5-7 pages long.

I need to suppress the page header on the first page of each group

How can I do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Mark Bannister's suggestion is a good way to go. If you're looking for a step-by-step, here is my $0.02:

1. Open your **section expert** (right click on some white space, you should see it come up).
2. Go to the options for the **group footer** and turn on **reset page numbers after**. You should see the page numbers reset at the beginning of each report.
3. Also in the section expert, go to the options for the **page header** and click on the blue button next to the **Suppress (No Drill-Down)** option.
4. In the **Formula Editor**, enter **PageNumber=1**

Answer (score 10):

If you have reset the page number to 1 on change of group (as mentioned in your other question), then enter the formula

```
PageNumber=1
```

in the "Suppress (No Drill-Down)" formula option in the Section Expert for the Group Header section, in the Crystal Reports Designer.

Answer (score 2):

To hide the header for pages that are not page 1, you would change the Formula Editor, enter PageNumber > 1

Comment: This is the simplest answer!

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code to your Crystal Report Designer.  Use the same code for your page footer.

```
'--------for Header--------------------------------------------------
Private Sub rptPageHeader_Format(ByVal pFormattingInfo As Object)
    If PageNum.Value = 1 Then
        rptPageHeader.Suppress = True
    Else
        rptPageHeader.Suppress = False
    End If
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Joe,

How do I put this code in the report with the designer? Do I need to create a function or something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for multiple pages, and not the pages 1

```
if TotalPageCount > 1 then pagenumber < TotalPagecount
```