# How to suppress a page header on page header and first page of a group?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a report where each group is about 5-7 pages long.

1. I need to suppress the page header on the first page of each group
2. Also I want to Supress the header on each group change (on first age on group)

**Note : I don't want to reset page no after each group change.**

I found solution for point 1 :

[Crystal Reports - How to suppress a page header on the first page of a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199339/)

**Now I am looking for point 2 solution.**
How can I do this? Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also supress Group header same as Page header but you have to add condition for that like

```
Boolean RetValue=false;
If(GroupNo==OldGroupNo)
       RetValue=True;
Return RetValue;
```

In this OldGroupNo is Shared Variable which change in WhilePrintingRecord Function in Detail Section. You have to  manage OldGroupNo In Detail section and then supress it.
May be this Help to you.....

Comment: Thanks Manoj.I am new to crytal report.Kindly explain me how I can create OldGroupNo  and  GroupNo fields .Or give me link where I can study about it.

Comment: Hi Preeti,
You can Find http://p2p.wrox.com/crystal-reports/40991-shared-variable-problem-crystal-reports-8-5-a.html AND http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/26316-Adding-Sub-reports-Find-Sub-Total-Grand.aspx

Let me know is this link used or not?
Also accept my answer if you got any help