# How to suppress Page Header when I have a Cross Tab in Report Footer in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab, suppress

I was wondering how to suppress the page header on a report only where my Cross Tab is shown on the report (which is at the end in the Report Footer section). I've re-set my paging after a section so my Cross Tab pages start fresh. Is there a formula to suppress if page numbers are duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy, you can give condition in section expert.

in Section Expert for the page header in the Suppress X-1 button try:
OnLastRecord. Refer link(http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=10201)

[Crystal Reports - Suppress a Page Header if the page has 0 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294027/crystal-reports-suppress-a-page-header-if-the-page-has-0-records)

[Crystal Reports - How to suppress a page header on the first page of a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199339/crystal-reports-how-to-suppress-a-page-header-on-the-first-page-of-a-group)

http://businessintelligence.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/businessobjects-crystal-l/suppress-page-header-and-page-footer-on-the-report-footer-2715858